# Spark SQL - Select yields AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'api'

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

Good day,

I'm using a base install of `Azure HDinsight cluster`, configured for `spark`.
I'm in `Jupyter Notebook`, `PySpark`.

Working in the provided 00 - [READ ME FIRST] `PySpark Kernel Features.ipynb file`, I've found the following error/bug when executing a `spark sql 'SELECT'`:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'api'

Executed code:

---

```
%%sql -o query1

SELECT clientid, querytime, deviceplatform, querydwelltime

FROM hivesampletable

WHERE state = 'Washington' AND devicemake = 'Microsoft'
```

---

I've had the same error show up when using `SELECT` in other code. Since the code noted here appears in the provided baseline 'tutorial', I expect its not a coding error.  I've had the same error in `PySpark` and `PySpark 3 kernel`.

*Does anyone have any experience/advice/suggestions they can share?*

Trace:

---

> AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>   /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc
>   in **call**(self, obj)

```
 902                 pass

 903             else:

 --> 904                 printer(obj)

 905                 return True

 906             # Finally look for special method names
```

*/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autovizwidget/widget/utils.pyc* in `display_dataframe(df)`

```
114 

115 def display_dataframe(df):

 --> 116     selected_x = select_x(df)

117     selected_y = select_y(df, selected_x)

118     encoding = Encoding(chart_type=Encoding.chart_type_table, x=selected_x, y=selected_y,
```

*/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autovizwidget/widget/utils.pyc* in `select_x(data, order)`

```
 70         _validate_custom_order(order)

 71 

 ---> 72     d = _classify_data_by_type(data, order)

 73 

 74     chosen_x = None
```

*/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autovizwidget/widget/utils.pyc* in `_classify_data_by_type(data, order, skip)`

```
 48     for column_name in data:

 49         if column_name not in skip:

 ---> 50             typ = infer_vegalite_type(data[column_name])

 51             d[typ].append(column_name)

 52
```

*/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autovizwidget/widget/utils.pyc* in `infer_vegalite_type(data)`

```
 14     """

 15 

 ---> 16     typ = pd.api.types.infer_dtype(data)

 17 

 18     if typ in ['floating', 'mixed-integer-float', 'integer',
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'api'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebook is using version 0.17.1 of pandas but the autovizwidget depends on a later version of pandas that has the 'api' module. I've been told that this will be resolved in a subsequent release of HDInsight configs.

ssh into the cluster and run the following:

`sudo -HE /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I used:

pip install pandas --upgrade --user

via the terminal available in the jupyter notebook.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into same issue from these instructions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-load-data-run-query and the just swapped to use *pySpark3* and all was good